# Prove that for positive $a_n$, and $b_n$ any rearrangement of $a_n$, one has $\sum \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n $

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for any rearrangement of $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n$ of the positive numbers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ one has $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{a_i }{b_i} \geq n$.

### Attempt:

First, one can write $\sum \frac{a_i}{b_i} = \sum \dfrac{a_i + b_i }{b_i} - n \geq n$ so we can prove

$$ \sum \dfrac{ a_i + b_i }{b_i} \geq 2n \iff \sum \dfrac{a_i + b_i }{2b_i} \geq n $$

and we a sum of $n$ numbers of the form $\dfrac{ a_i + b_i }{2b_i} \geq \dfrac{\sqrt{a_i b_i } }{ b_i} = \sqrt{ \dfrac{ a_i}{b_i} }$. I see a no-end from here since it is not always true that $a_i \geq b_i$.

....

Other strategy is perhaps use induction? If $n=2$, then we have $(a_1,a_2)$ an if $b_i = a_i$ then we have the result easily. If $b_1 = a_2$, then

$$ \dfrac{a_1}{a_2} + \dfrac{a_2}{a_1} \geq 2 $$

which follows because $x + 1/x \geq 2 $. Now, suppose result is true for $n$ then

$$ \sum^{n} \dfrac{a_i}{b_i} + \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \geq n + \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1} } $$

how can one prove that $a_{n+1} \geq b_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Maybe just a direct result of the rearrangement inequality?

Comment: Just apply the AM-GM inequality to the fractions $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$.

Comment: Got it! because $\sum \dfrac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n ( \prod \frac{a_i}{b+i} )^{1/n} = n $. Correct? Thanks profesor! Write it as an answer to reward you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would follow from the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).